# awk compare value with a input

Tags: linux, bash, awk

can a user input variable($userinput) compare with a value?

```
awk -F:  '$1 < $userinput { printf .... }'
```

This comparison expression seems ok to me, but it gives an error?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try doing this :

```
awk -vuserinput="$userinput" -F: '$1 < userinput {}'
```

A real example :

```
read -p "Give me an integer >>> " int
awk -v input=$int '$1 < input {print $1, "is less than", input}' <<< 1
```